# Jtransforms use in Android studio 2.3.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to use jtransforms in my project. I am new to android studio. I added the jatransoforms-with-dependencies.jar file as a new module.

Some other posts suggested to add jtransforms jar to the libs folder but there are many libs folders when I did a search and none of them show in the left hand side of the android studio dialog box (which shows the programs).

Now they also asked to do this
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}

The above two steps I could not do so I added the jar as a module from right clicking on the dialog box on the left side which shows project names. Now I am unable to delete the module (also please tell me how to remove this).

So lastly when I did this
import org.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D; 
it says "cannot resolve symbol DoubleFFT_1D".

There are many posts online to add a .jar file but and are varied (depend upon editor / studio version etc). Please tell me how do I add (and remove) the jar file to my project, use jtransforms FFT function.( i read other posts but were not useful).

Comment: There shall be `+` and `-` button in green and red color , just select the module and click on `-` in red color . You can delete your module easily . Try it .

Comment: Any idea on how to use jtransforms in a project in android studio 2.3.2?  Cant see any signs here: http://imgur.com/a/SdlkP